beginCollision callback not allowing two fixtures
Here's where I set the callbacks:
GameWorld = love.physics.newWorld(0, 0, true)
GameWorld:setCallbacks(self.contact)

Here's the contact method:
function thisScene:contact(a, b, coll)
    print(a, b, coll)
end

Output: Fixture: 0x56e2fcb072a0 Contact: 0x56e2fd2d92e0 nil
As you can see a is a fixture while b is a contact.
I was expecting a and b to be the two fixtures that collided and coll to be the contact.
Love Version: 11.3
Thanks in advance!

I figured it out. The first argument was thisScene due to the ":"
Corrected code:
function thisScene.contact(a, b, coll)

